# Writing SF Dataframe to Microsoft SQL Server Crashes R and Fails to Write Data

Tags: r, sql-server, odbc, r-sf

Using the sample data provided, I am trying to write an `sf` dataframe out to a Microsoft SQL Server table, following the instructions found [here](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/reference/st_write.html), however, whenever I do so, the R Session crashes and gives the error shown in the screen shot below.

I am wondering if anyone else has seen this problem and what they did to resolve it?

As always, thank you in advance.

-nate

Error From Terminal:

```
Note: method with signature ‘DBIObject#sf’ chosen for function ‘dbDataType’,
 target signature ‘Microsoft SQL Server#sf’.
 "OdbcConnection#ANY" would also be valid

 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x21, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: result_insert_dataframe(rs@ptr, values, batch_rows)
 2: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
 3: tryCatch(result_insert_dataframe(rs@ptr, values, batch_rows),     finally = dbClearResult(rs))
 4: .local(conn, name, value, ...)
 5: dbWriteTable(conn, name, to_postgis(conn, value, binary), ...,     row.names = row.names, overwrite = overwrite, append = append,     field.types = field.types)
 6: dbWriteTable(conn, name, to_postgis(conn, value, binary), ...,     row.names = row.names, overwrite = overwrite, append = append,     field.types = field.types)
 7: .local(conn, name, value, ...)
 8: DBI::dbWriteTable(conn = con, name = the_table_name, value = polygon_db,     row.names = FALSE, overwrite = TRUE, binary = TRUE)
 9: DBI::dbWriteTable(conn = con, name = the_table_name, value = polygon_db,     row.names = FALSE, overwrite = TRUE, binary = TRUE)
An irrecoverable exception occurred. R is aborting now ...
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Session Info:

```
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.4

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] odbc_1.2.2   DBI_1.1.0    magrittr_1.5 sf_0.9-3    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.4.6       class_7.3-16       packrat_0.5.0      grid_3.6.3         e1071_1.7-3        units_0.6-6        KernSmooth_2.23-16 rlang_0.4.6        blob_1.2.1         vctrs_0.2.4        tools_3.6.3        bit64_0.9-7       
[13] bit_1.1-15.2       hms_0.5.3          compiler_3.6.3     pkgconfig_2.0.3    classInt_0.4-3
```

Sample Data (Apologies for long lines):

```r
polygon_sf_df <- structure(
  list(leaf_id = c(1234, 2222),
       db_label = c("Middle of Nothing", "Somewhere in Florida"),
       division = c("Mountain", "South Atlantic"),
       geometry = structure(list(
         structure(list(structure(c(-114.806444, -114.326789, -114.08946, -114.898877, -114.806444, 39.236959, 39.219554, 38.961837, 38.829708, 39.236959), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")),
         structure(list(structure(c(-81.806444, -81.326789, -81.08946, -81.898877, -81.806444, 29.236959, 29.219554, 28.961837, 28.829708, 29.236959), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg"))),
         class = c("sfc_POLYGON", "sfc"), precision = 0,
         bbox = structure(c(xmin = -114.898877, ymin = 28.829708, xmax = -81.08946, ymax = 39.236959), class = "bbox"),
         crs = structure(list(input = "EPSG:4326", wkt = "GEOGCS[\"WGS 84\",\n    DATUM[\"WGS_1984\",\n        SPHEROID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n            AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"7030\"]],\n        AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"6326\"]],\n    PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n        AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"8901\"]],\n    UNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433,\n        AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"9122\"]],\n    AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"4326\"]]"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)),
  sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(leaf_id = NA_integer_, db_label = NA_integer_, division = NA_integer_), .Label = c("constant", "aggregate", "identity"), class = "factor"),
  row.names = 1:2, class = c("sf", "data.frame"))
```

Quick Package Installs:

```r
options(scipen = 999)
ipak <- function(pkg){
  new.pkg <- pkg[!(pkg %in% installed.packages()[, "Package"])]
  if (length(new.pkg)) 
    install.packages(new.pkg, dependencies = TRUE)
  sapply(pkg, require, character.only = TRUE)
}
packages<- c("sf", "magrittr","DBI", "odbc")
ipak(packages)
```

Connection & Writing Method:

```r
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                      Driver   = "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server",
                      Server   = "some_database_server.windows.net",
                      Database = "dev_db",
                      UID      = "<User ID Here>",
                      PWD      = "<PW HERE>",
                      Port     = 1433, 
                      maxvarcharsize = 0)
# Fails Here
DBI::dbWriteTable(conn = con, name = "the_sf_polygon_table_name", value = polygon_sf_df, row.names=FALSE, overwrite=TRUE, binary=TRUE)
```

The Schema of the table (as per comments below)

```
structure(list(TABLE_CATALOG = c("analytics_dev", "analytics_dev", 
"analytics_dev", "analytics_dev"), TABLE_SCHEMA = c("dbo", "dbo", 
"dbo", "dbo"), TABLE_NAME = c("test_polygon_table", "test_polygon_table", 
"test_polygon_table", "test_polygon_table"), COLUMN_NAME = c("leaf_id", 
"db_label", "division", "geometry"), ORDINAL_POSITION = 1:4, 
    COLUMN_DEFAULT = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_), IS_NULLABLE = c("YES", "YES", "YES", "YES"
    ), DATA_TYPE = c("float", "varchar", "varchar", "geometry"
    ), CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH = c(NA, 255L, 255L, -1L), CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH = c(NA, 
    255L, 255L, -1L), NUMERIC_PRECISION = c(53L, NA, NA, NA), 
    NUMERIC_PRECISION_RADIX = c(2L, NA, NA, NA), NUMERIC_SCALE = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), DATETIME_PRECISION = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), CHARACTER_SET_CATALOG = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), CHARACTER_SET_SCHEMA = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), CHARACTER_SET_NAME = c(NA, 
    "iso_1", "iso_1", NA), COLLATION_CATALOG = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), COLLATION_SCHEMA = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), COLLATION_NAME = c(NA, 
    "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS", "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS", 
    NA), DOMAIN_CATALOG = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_), DOMAIN_SCHEMA = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_), DOMAIN_NAME = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: (1) Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly. (2) I'm going to *guess* that this has to do with the schema, please provide it. (3) If there are any errors specific to SQL Server (typically starting with `[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]...`), please include those as well.

Comment: the schema is dbo.table1, dbo.table2, dbo.the_sf_polygon_table_name... within the polygon table, the columns are exactly what the demo data set contains. Does this help?

Comment: Nope. By schema I meant what the column types are. You are trying to insert nested lists, which only have context in a couple of datatypes ... and I believe that R does not automate either of those types, so you'll have to do them manually. But I don't want to go down that road without knowing what the *database* thinks the tables look like. Perhaps insert the output from `"select * from information_schema.columns where table_name='the_sf_polygon_table_name'"` into your question? I don't need most fields, but I don't have all handy in my brain ...

Comment: (When I said I don't need most fields, I meant most fields from the `information_schema.columns` query ... I think `select column_name, data_type, character_maximum_length ...` would suffice ... Feel free to obfuscate/remove other columns like `table_catalog`, `table_schema`, and `table_name`, those are not important. Frankly, `column_name` doesn't need to be real, as long as we know what `data_type` and some of the other fields look like.)

Comment: @r2evans I just updated the question with the schema info.

Comment: Thanks, nate. I just tried some of the example code from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/spatial-types-geometry-transact-sql, and in my case it appears that DBI and `odbc` treat the `geometry` column as `character` (similar perhaps to `nvarchar(max)`). Because of this, I believe you can't use "blob" (R-native `list` or `sf`), you'll need some form of translation layer. Not sure this helps, I don't have any experience with SQLServer's `geometry` class.

Comment: (JIncidentally, on quick reading it seems the [`geography::`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/create-construct-and-query-geography-instances) set of functions in SQL Server are more appropriate for GPS coordinates than [`geometry::`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/create-construct-and-query-geometry-instances). I don't think that changes the question at all, but if you're dealing with actual lat/lon and datums and ellipsoid/gps stuff, then I wonder if `geography` would be better.)

Comment: @r2evans ... wonderful insights. This is all stuff I did not know. Thank you. Since we're not going to be doing geospatial joins or lookups from any queries (at least not yet), one idea I had was to convert the `geometry` column to character (i.e. a string that says `list(123, 124,..., 45, 45.5)` and then writing that out to the DB. I would have to go through the hassle of rebuilding the geometry and `sf` object(s) in R after I read in the file, which I'm less confident in given I'm not sure what the format the coordinates are actually stored in (WKT?), but it's a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a hack, to be honest, since I'm not familiar or proficient with `sf` (R package) or `geometry` (sql server data type). Up front, I wonder if `geography` (sql server data type) might be more appropriate for you, since it alleges to be for GPS-like coordinates (datums, etc) ... but I think this process might translate just as well.

Either way, I first show how R and SQL Server agree on the shapes (spoiler: `character`), and then how to read and push those to the database in proper data types.

### Query

If you step through the examples in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/spatial-types-geometry-transact-sql and then run a query, notice what it returns:

```r
# con <- DBI::dbConnect(...) # sql server
DBI::dbExecute(con, "
CREATE TABLE SpatialTable   
    ( id int IDENTITY (1,1),  
    GeomCol1 geometry,   
    GeomCol2 AS GeomCol1.STAsText() )")

DBI::dbExecute(con, "
INSERT INTO SpatialTable (GeomCol1)  
VALUES (geometry::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING (100 100, 20 180, 180 180)', 0));  
INSERT INTO SpatialTable (GeomCol1)  
VALUES (geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON ((0 0, 150 0, 150 150, 0 150, 0 0))', 0));  ")

ret <- DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "select * from SpatialTable")
str(ret)
# 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ id      : int  1 2
#  $ GeomCol1: chr  "" ""
#  $ GeomCol2: chr  "LINESTRING (100 100, 20 180, 180 180)" "POLYGON ((0 0, 150 0, 150 150, 0 150, 0 0))"
```

Not a surprise (to me), DBI treats this like a string. Note, though, that it's returning something for `GeomCol2`, which is a text-translation of the actual blob-like field `GeomCol1`. And nothing for `GeomCol1`. Okay, let's only retrieve what we need, and since the "id" if a geometry is not intended to be numerical, let's convert it to a string then confirm it plots:

```r
ret <- DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "select id, GeomCol2 from SpatialTable")
ret$id <- as.character(ret$id)
plot(sf::st_as_sf(ret, wkt="GeomCol2"))
```

[image: simple sf sample plot]

### Upload

In order to upload your data to SQL Server, we need to `character`-ize it.

```r
tempdat <- as.data.frame(polygon_sf_df)[,c("leaf_id", "geometry")]
tempdat$geometry <- sapply(tempdat$geometry, format, width = 0)
names(tempdat)[1] <- "id"
str(tempdat)
# 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ id      : num  1234 2222
#  $ geometry: chr  "POLYGON ((-114.8064 39.23696, -114.3268 39.21955, -114.0895 38.96184, -114.8989 38.82971, -114.8064 39.23696))" "POLYGON ((-81.80644 29.23696, -81.32679 29.21955, -81.08946 28.96184, -81.89888 28.82971, -81.80644 29.23696))"
```

Now we can upload it to a temp table:

```r
### write *character* shapes to a temp table
DBI::dbWriteTable(con, "temptable", tempdat, create = TRUE)
### convert those *character* shapes to real *geometries*
DBI::dbExecute(con, "
insert into SpatialTable (GeomCol1)
select geometry::STGeomFromText(geometry, 0) as GeomCol1
from temptable")
DBI::dbExecute(con, "drop table temptable")
```

Now we can query those shapes:

```r
ret2 <- DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "select id, GeomCol2 from SpatialTable where id > 2")
ret2$id <- as.character(ret2$id)
ret2 <- sf::st_as_sf(ret2, wkt="GeomCol2")
ret2
# Simple feature collection with 2 features and 1 field
# geometry type:  POLYGON
# dimension:      XY
# bbox:           xmin: -114.8989 ymin: 28.82971 xmax: -81.08946 ymax: 39.23696
# CRS:            NA
#   id                       GeomCol2
# 1  3 POLYGON ((-114.8064 39.2369...
# 2  4 POLYGON ((-81.80644 29.2369...

plot(ret2)
```

[image: OP shapes through the database]

### Note about data size

Without extensive testing, my guess is that this text field (when queried) will be "large" in the SQL Server sense; this is a "known thing" in that Microsoft's ODBC driver intentionally breaks when "large fields" are not last in the selection of columns. For this, then, make sure that the geometry-text field is among the last columns in your query (not before any not-large fields).

References:

- ODBC driver comments, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/develop-app/getting-long-data, it is known and apparently by-design, so a "feature"
- `odbc` package discussion, https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/issues/112, external to the package so not going to be fixed
- nanodbc (library used by the `odbc` package`) has discussed this twice and concluded that it is also not their problem to fix ([#8](https://github.com/nanodbc/nanodbc/issues/8#issuecomment-336588681) and [#149](https://github.com/nanodbc/nanodbc/issues/149))

Comment: First, fabulous answer. I am so grateful for your help. Thank you. I am going to use your answer, but also post my own just so you can see my 'hack'. Also, love your comments about ODBC drivers.

Comment: Thanks. To me, it's a very frustrating state that the originator of the ODBC protocol imposes a requirement on their own driver (that no other driver implements) for something that is not posed as a requirement in the protocol, either specifically or inferentially. They just do. When colleagues/partners write views or stored-procs that do not order columns favorably, either (a) I have to use `bcp` or `sqlcmd` to get the data external to ODBC; or (b) I cannot use that view or proc. I've seen nothing but negative press about that restriction, and there are no viable alternatives for windows.

Answer (score 0):

This is the workaround I came up with...It is basically the same thing @r2evans. I am very grateful for his help.

Steps:

1. Turn the actual polygon (`geometry` column) into a line/polygon string
2. Drop the old geometry column from the existing dataframe
3. Write the new data with the string/character column (I call it `geo`) out the the DB
4. Read from the DB (`select * from whatever`)
5. Convert it back to a `geometry` for use in R

Code:

```
# Converting To String/Character, Writing To DB:
polygon_sf_df$geo<- sf::st_as_text(polygon_sf_df$geometry)
polygon_sf_df<- polygon_sf_df %>% sf::st_set_geometry(NULL)

the_table_name<- paste0("test_polygon_table")
DBI::dbWriteTable(conn = con, name = the_table_name, value = polygon_sf_df, row.names=FALSE, overwrite=TRUE, binary=TRUE)

## Reading back IN:
tmp<- DBI::dbSendQuery(conn=con, statement = paste0("SELECT * FROM dbo.", the_table_name))
polygon_df_ret<- DBI::dbFetch(tmp)
polygon_df_ret$geometry<- sf::st_as_sfc(polygon_df_ret$geo)
polygon_df_ret$geo<- NULL
polygon_df_ret<- sf::st_as_sf(polygon_df_ret)
```